# Random population generation between bounds

Tags: matlab, random, population

How can I have to generate a random population of size 7x100 with each element being between -10 and 10. Whats the fastest way to do it without using loops?

Comment: The fastest way to do it is to read the manual http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/rand.html

Answer (score 8):

If you want the data to be uniformly distributed, you can call [`rand`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/rand.html) and adjust the range.

```
out = (rand(7,100)-0.5)*20;
```

If the data should follow a different distribution, you can use any of a [long list of functions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/stats/bq_w_hm.html#bq_w_ie-15) that generate random numbers from a specific distribution, but you'll have to adjust the range differently, of course.

Answer (score 2):

If you're generating uniformly-distributed *integer* values between -10 and 10, the function [RANDI](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/randi.html) makes this very easy:

```
randValues = randi([-10 10],[7 100]);
```